# Why does this code throw an IndexError only when run on my CA?

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a .csv file with names and scores. Here are the files contents (The name and score are in separate columns):

```
Bob 1
Dave 6
Linda 9.76
Andy 90
hilary 87
mathew 6.4576589
```

The program should display the scores from highest to lowest. Like this:

```
Bob 1
Dave 6
mathew 6.4576589 
Linda 9.76
hilary 89
Andy 90
```

I have been trying this for ages. Here is my code below:

```
import csv
import operator
out_file = open('class1_scores_max.csv','r')
scores1 = csv.reader(out_file,delimiter=',')
sort = sorted(scores1,key = lambda x: float(x[1]))
for eachline in sort:
    final = eachline[0]," ",eachline[1]
    print (''.join(final))
```

This work perfectly in a separate python file but in my main Controlled Assessment in school it comes up with the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

In my main code at school it is part of a definition (sub-routine). Can anyone help?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provided the **full** error message instead of the last line only. Paste everything from the `Traceback` to the line you already included.  To me it looks like you have a line in your csv with too few values.

Comment: If you don't mind explaining, what is a CA?

Comment: CA is controlled assesment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've provided, you're getting an `IndexError` at either of these two lines:

```
sort = sorted(scores1,key = lambda x: float(x[1]))
```

or

```
    final = eachline[0]," ",eachline[1]
```

I suspect that you're `IndexError` is at the first line, because getting an `IndexError` at the second line seems to imply that it would've occured at the first as well.

You can fix this by making sure there's two elements in each line before sorting and printing them.

```
sort = sorted([x for x in scores1 if len(x) == 2], key = lambda x: float(x[1]))
```

---

This is also a great time to learn the basics of debugging. Suppose you didn't have help from the internet and had to debug this problem on your own. Adding a few print statements is one of the quickest and simplest ways to debug code. For example,

```
import csv
import operator
out_file = open('class1_scores_max.csv','r')
scores1 = csv.reader(out_file,delimiter=',')
for score in scores1:
    print score
sort = sorted(scores1,key = lambda x: float(x[1]))
for eachline in sort:
    final = eachline[0]," ",eachline[1]
    print (''.join(final))
```

Notice where I inserted the following lines:

```
for score in scores1:
    print score
```

This will allow you to see if there's anything in `scores1` that might lead to an `IndexError` later on when you try to access the first and second elements of a an element in `scores1`.

Comment: Thanks!!! @gragas That really helped. Your a life saver. I'll keep in mind your tip on the "basics of debugging' for next time. I am fairly new to python and programming in general.